# How to get of coordinates of A?

Tags: geometry

Let I have given a triangle $ABC$ . The mid points coordinates of the $AB$ is $(-2,-1)$, mid point of $BC$ is $(3,-5)$, and mid point of $CA$ is $(5,-1)$. If I have to use the center of mass formula it get complicated.  Lots of unknowns are messing. Is there any easy way to find the coordinates of coordinate $A$?

Comment: Another suggestion. Let $A' = (3,-5)$, $B' = (5,-1)$ and $C' = (-2,-1)$ be the midpoints of the sides opposite $A$, $B$ and $C$, respectively. To find $A$, draw the line through $B'$ that is parallel to $A'C'$, and the line through $C'$ that is parallel to $A'B'$. Then $A$ is the point of intersection of the two lines. This can be done computationally by finding the equations of the lines. Numerically, this isn't very nice, but geometrically, it's quite satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D(-2,-1),E(3,-5),F(5,-1)$.

Then, since $AB$ is parallel to $EF$, the line $AB$ is
$$y-(-1)=\frac{-1-(-5)}{5-3}(x-(-2))\iff y=2x+3\tag1$$
Also, since $AC$ is parallel to $DE$, the line $AC$ is
$$y-(-1)=\frac{-5-(-1)}{3-(-2)}(x-5)\iff y=-\frac 45x+3\tag2$$
Now, since the point $A$ is the intersection point of $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get $A(0,3)$.

Comment: in question they have not mentioned that AB is parallel to EF. Can we guess so because of their midpoint?

Comment: @SabbirHasan: Yes, exactly. See the following page :http://users.humboldt.edu/flashman/mdptthrm.html

Comment: @SabbirHasan: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I will solve the $x$ coordinate of the point $A$ for you, then the $y$ coordinate you do.

Remember that, give two points $P,Q$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $P(x_P,y_P)$ and $Q(x_Q,y_Q)$ the medim point $M$ is $\left(\frac{x_P+x_Q}{2},\frac{y_P+y_Q}{2}\right)$.

Now the question says:

$$x_A+x_B=-4\qquad (1)$$
$$x_B+x_C=6\qquad (2)$$
$$x_C+x_A=10\qquad (3)$$

Doing $(1)-(2)+(3)$, we have
$$x_A+x_B-x_B-x_C+x_C+x_A=-4-6+10$$
$$2x_A=0$$
$$x_A=0.$$

Now it's you turn!